# Loop to execute a stored procedure for month end dates

Tags: sql, loops

I am looking for some help with a `loop` that will allow me to `execute` a stored procedure multiple times for each month end from January 2016 until January 2021. I have access to a `calendar` which gives me the each month end (as below). I need to `execute` each stored procedure like this:- `EXECUTE usp_something @asatdate`

```
SELECT TOP 100.*
FROM dbo.Dim_Calendar
WHERE iscalendarmonthend = 1
```

I've got no experience with `Loops` at all and have always been told not to ever use them, so I am a little apprehensive, so will ensure that I will test this fully locally.

Thank you.

Comment: please edit question and tag with database.

Comment: Please also edit question and show table definitions, example data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

As long as your query above pulls only the month-end dates you're expecting to run through your stored procedure, you could loop it with a cursor, as below.

```
DECLARE @asatdate DATETIME

DECLARE CURSOR_DB CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT MonthEndDate
    FROM dbo.Dim_Calendar
    WHERE iscalendarmonthend = 1
 
OPEN CURSOR_DB
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_DB INTO @asatdate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXECUTE usp_something @asatdate

    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_DB INTO @asatdate

END
CLOSE CURSOR_DB
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_DB
```